# Breaking down the hex value for output 1

Tags: script, raw-transaction, output, createrawtransaction

Within the hex generated by `createrawtransaction`, I am trying to understand the output 1 hex.

The output 1 hex I have is:

> 76a9**14**ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e788ac

Spacing out the sections:

> 76 a9 **14** ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e7 88 ac

Breaking it down further:

> 76 = OP_DUP
>
> a9 = OP_HASH160
>
> **14 = ?**
>
> ab68025513c3dbd2f7b92a94e0581f5d50f654e7 = HASH160(pubKey)
>
> 88 = OP_EQUALVERIFY
>
> ac = OP_CHECKSIG

What does that **14** mean/represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a push op code. 0x14 (20 in decimal) tells the script to that the next 20 bytes must be pushed to the stack (the hash).

You can view a full list of OP_CODEs [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Opcodes).

Answer (score 1):

Values from `1-75` represent a number of bytes to be pushed into the stack. I that case, `14 hex` is `20 dec`, and will push the `20 bytes` of the `hash160`.